# Hibernate criteria : the origin class

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I was wondering if there was a way to get the name of the class that was used to create the criteria.

Example :

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(MyClasse.class)
```

So I would like to know, when I have the criteria c, that MyClasse was used to make it

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Criteria's Entity or ClassName by,

```
 Criteria c = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Customer.class);
((CriteriaImpl) c).getEntityOrClassName() - would give you Customer
```

- Maddy